# Wordpress search including multiple categories

Tags: wordpress, search

I have a search form that has a text field and 3 drop downs, that have categories. What I'm trying to achieve is the current search query that posts appears as follows:

?s=Milk&cat=4&cat=7&cat=15.

What I'm trying to achieve is something like:

?s=Milk&cat=04,7,15

I'm relatively new to WordPress and PHP and haven't been able to find any good documentation or references to what I need to do to accomplish this.

I don't necessarily want the answer, just some guidance in the right direction.

Comment: Not very helpful but why?

Comment: What's not very helpful? I'm would like the query include the categories from the dropdown fields. I know that the query that posts needs to have categories be comma separated; I just need to figure out how to strip the two extra &cat= from the query so that all three categories are queried.

Answer (score 0):

This was already answer: [multiple categories query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/3696)

It must be like this:

/?cat=970,971,972 where the # is the cat id.

Comment: I hadn't come across that article over the past few days. Thanks for sharing; I'll check it out. I have the cat id's going into the query, I just haven't been able to figure out how to strip the extra &cat=

Comment: I figured this out by creating a function that intercepts the $_GET variables being submitted, then put each of the values in an array if the value wasn't equal to 0. Once the array was built I added a filter to the global search query object, used the pre_get_posts function/hook with my custom function and achieved what I wanted to achieve.